# Remove rows from gridview with jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net, gridview

I am new using Jquery. I am using vb.net 2008, and I have built a gridview and populated it with data.  I am trying to use jquery to go in and remove rows if one of the attributes of the row does not equal the user that I am currently looking at.

The attached link (http://jsfiddle.net/FJXRN/1/) shows the example of who is logged in and where his id is being displayed in a label at the top of the page and I am trying to search the rows of the grid view and deselect the checkbox for that row and hide the row of the gridview if they do not contain the same userid.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you filter these results in code-behind?

Comment: We have filtered them out in the code behind, but are currently trying to do an additional check on the data to make sure we are removing everything correctly.  We are experencing a random bug that in not reoccurring to any particular user, that seems to be quickly solved by the user refreshing the page.  We are basically trying to double check the data before the user see and complains.

Comment: Can you post the filtering code and tell us when you're filtering the users?

Comment: The inital filtering of the data? It is a query where a particular field equals the userid?  When trying to reproduce the error we have been unsuccessful, but we have received screen shots of the error.

Comment: You're filtering your users out in a SQL query and they're still showing up here? My point is, you'll probably be better off trying to fix the source of the problem than trying to find a workaround like this.

Comment: We have been looking into fixing the source of the problem, but it is hard to fix an error when we can't reproduce it.

Comment: I understand, but the point remains. If you're having a problem with your SQL query, why not ask a question about potential problems with that query? This workaround is going to leave you with a bloated, tightly-coupled, and insecure codebase when you could have a much better working solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you should do this in the front end.  Note that you have an extra space in your html element for your user ID label which I removed:

http://jsfiddle.net/FJXRN/8/

please note you should have that javascript code within your document ready function in your javascript file. if you want to put it back in a function feel free to do that

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have tweaked it a little to remove the user column as well. <http://jsfiddle.net/FJXRN/13/>